# Show that f is entire

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $g$ is a non constant polynomial, f is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$, if the function $h=f\circ g$ is entire, show that $f$ is entire.

I have no idea about this question. Maybe Taylor series will be the tool?
Thanks

Comment: What happens if $ g(z)=z^2$ or $g(z) = z^3+1$ ? Then try to figure how $g^{−1}$ fails to be analytic "at some points" (which ones ?) and look at $h \circ g^{-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g$ takes all complex values.  In a neighbourhood of $g(z)$ where $g'(z) \ne 0$, $g$ is invertible and $f = h \circ g^{-1}$.  Any singularities are removable.